# Getting rid off "File still marked as conflicted" warning in Xcode

Tags: git, xcode6, compiler-warnings

I would like to remove the warning. It is not easy to find the point which causes this warning. There is no log in xcode after clicking on the yellow icon, just a blank page. The warning is in the project file, not the workspace file. It is also not related to the current git state. The information about the conflict is stored somewhere in the .xcodeproj. But I could not find any related line. I suspect it was caused by a canceled merge (the process could not be finished) from Xcode.

XCode 6.4, git version 2.3.2 (Apple Git-55)

[image]

I can not remove the warning via the menu:

[image]

It looks like a zombie warning from a previous conflict that is stored somewhere. I tried to

- remove the workspace file and create a new one (with pod install)
- I have searched everywhere for <<<<< or >>>>> or "conflict" lines
- searched in the project file for any clue related to the TSNLocalEntityCompetition
- removed the xcuserdata file from .xcodeproj package
- removed folders with derivates, cleaned project, the warning is still there

I can build the project and run the application without problem.

git status

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:   TSN.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/TSN.xccheckout
modified:   TSN.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/slavik.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: In a non-IDE environment you need to `git add` after you have resolved the conflict, what is the output from `git status`?

Comment: @joran I have update the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are satisfied with the merge (check with `git diff`) you need to add, commit and push the files that has been merged:

```
git add --update
git commit -m "A merge commit message"
git push origin master
```

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like the warning is stored somewhere in the project files, in a binary or in a form of a UID. Maybe it could be a user related cache. The git says everything is ok.

Comment: @VladimírSlavík, sometimes you may need to refresh the IDE after you have made changes from the CLI (at least with Eclipse)

Comment: It does not appear on a different macbook. At least my colleagues are not bothered with that. It is really bound to the ide settings/cache. I have cleared derivates/caches but I can still see that on my macbook.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by deleting the file and then undelete it. 
Make sure to backup the changes, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have untracked .orig files?  Try `git clean -f`

Comment: This I did also without success.

Comment: If you did git status though, did you see untracked files?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. After fixing the conflicts, all I had to do was commit my changes. In terminal

```
>>>cd myProjectFolder
>>>git commit -am "Fixed merge conflicts"
```

After that, the warnings went away for me.

Answer (score -4):

I had to remove the xcode from the system and install again. Resetting the xcode settings did not help.